# php test if string contains one of three strings?

Tags: php, string

What's the best way to achieve the following:

I have a `$img` variable containing e.g. `myimage_left.jgp`, `someimage_center.jpg` or `img_right.jpg`

What's the best way to test for `_left`, `_right` or `_center` of the filename and extract this value and store it in a variable?

So I have `$img` which already contains the complete basename of the file. And I need to have `$pos` which should hold `_center` or `_left` or `_right`.

What's the way to do that? preg_match, strpos, etc?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A regex would be simplest:

```
$input = 'foo_left.jpg';
if(!preg_match('/_(left|right|center)/', $input, $matches)) {
    // no match
}

$pos = $matches[0]; // "_left", "_right" or "_center"
```

[See it in action](http://ideone.com/3PyUv).

**Update:**

For a more defensive-minded approach (if there might be multiple instances of `"_left"` and 
friends in the filename), you can consider adding to the regex.

This will match only if the l/r/c is followed by a dot:

```
preg_match('/(_(left|right|center))\./', $input, $matches);
```

This will match only if the l/r/c is followed by the *last* dot in the filename (which practically means that the base name ends with the l/r/c specification):

```
preg_match('/(_(left|right|center))\\.[^\\.]*$/', $input, $matches);
```

And so on.

If using these regexes, you will find the result in `$matches[1]` instead of `$matches[0]`.

Comment: This won't work if _left|right|center happens to be in the middle of the string also

Comment: @Czechnology, It would match _left_blahblahblah.jpg. Not sure if thats legal.

Comment: @DougT.: Unless we can make *some* assumptions about the file name, life will be really hard. Think about `_left.jpg.I can have many 'extensions' if I want to.png_center.png`.

Comment: PS: You don't need to escape the dot in character groups, you can just write `[^.]`. Furthermore I would use a `+` there instead of an `*` in order to ensure that there is some file extension.

Comment: Actually, `$matches[0]` will contain the full string. You want `$matches[1]` which'll have the first capture group in it.

Comment: @MarcB: $matches[0] is good for the pre-update example. I 'll update the update to make it explicit though. :)

Answer (score 1):

Someone will probably have more elegant solution but I would use strpos like you suggest.

```
if (strpos(strtoupper($img), '_LEFT') > 0) $pos = '_LEFT'
```

you could then expand it to

```
$needleArray = arra('_LEFT', '_CENTER', '_RIGHT');
foreach ($needleArray as $needle) {
  if (strpos(strtoupper($img), $needle) > 0) $pos = $needle
}
```

This is assuming you can't have more than one value for pos.

Answer (score 1):

Non-regex option

```
$img = 'myimage_left.jpg';
$find = array( 'left', 'center', 'right' );

if ( in_array( $pos = end( explode( '_',  basename( $img, '.jpg' ) ) ), $find ) ) {
    echo $pos;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid regexes, you could just do

```
  $underScores = explode("_", $img);
  $endOfFileName = end($underScores);
  $withoutExtensionArr = explode(".", $img);
  $leftRightOrCenter = $withoutExtensionArr[0];
```

Then check the contents of left right or center