# PHP How to test whether one of the values of an array exists (partly) in a string?

Tags: php, string, if-statement

Must be simple but cant find my answer.
How to test whether one of the values in the array is contained in the string?
Output should be true or false.

```
$array = Array( 
   0 => 'word1',
   1 => 'word2',
   2 => 'New York'
   3 => 'New car' 
);

$string = "Its a sunny day in New York";
```

Trying to clarify. In this case array[3] should not be a match. Only array[2] should be.

Comment: Do you want to match whole words or just check whether the substrings in the are are anywhere in the string?

Comment: check if substrings are anywhere in the string

Comment: possible duplicate of [php test if string contains one of three strings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792625/php-test-if-string-contains-one-of-three-strings)

Comment: Regarding your edit: Then it is not anywhere in the string, it has to match word boundaries.

Comment: @Felix Kling, didn't thought of that, edited again the right way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

A word boundary independent solution would be to add spaces around the input string and the search words:

```
$str = ' ' . $str . ' ';


function quote($a) {
    return ' ' . preg_quote($a, '/') . ' ';
}

$word_pattern = '/' . implode('|', array_map('quote', $array)) . '/';

if(preg_match($word_pattern, $str) > 0) {

}
```

or by looping over the terms:

```
foreach($array as $term) {
    if (strpos($str, ' '. $term . ' ') !== false) {
        // word contained
    }
}
```

Both can be put in a function to simplify the use, e.g.

```
function contains($needle, $haystack) {
    $haystack = ' ' . $haystack . ' ';
    foreach($needle as $term) {
       if(strpos($haystack, ' ' . $term . ' ') !== false) {
           return true;
       }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Have a look at a [**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/6usum)

---

**Old answer:**

You could use regular expressions:

```
function quote($a) {
    return preg_quote($a, '/');
}

$word_pattern = implode('|', array_map('quote', $array));

if(preg_match('/\b' . $word_pattern  . '\b/', $str) > 0) {

}
```

The important part are the boundary characters `\b` here. You will only get a match if the value you search for is a (sequence of) word(s) in the string.

Comment: ty, but it could also be for more then one word edited example in op.

Comment: @Rob: Please have a look at my update. I think this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

The functional replacement for your `in_array` would be:

```
array_filter(
    array_map("strpos",  array_fill(0, count($words), $string), $words),
"is_int")
```

Answer (score 1):

A brute force method would be:

```
$words = implode('|', $array);

if (preg_match("/($words)/", $string, $matches)) {
    echo "found $matches[1]";
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to use `preg_quote`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = Array( 
   0 => 'word1',
   1 => 'word3',
   2 => 'word3 basic',
   3 => 'good'
);

$string = "there a good word3 basic here";

//Convert the String to an array
$stringArray = explode(' ',$string);

//Loop the string
foreach($stringArray as $matchedWords) {
    if(in_array($matchedWords, $array )) {
        echo $matchedWords.'<br/>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = Array( 
   0 => 'word1',
   1 => 'word2',
   2 => 'word3'
);

$string = "there a good word3 here";

foreach($array as $word)
{
    if(strstr($string, $word))
        echo "<b>$word</b> has been detected in <b>$string</b>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can se the in_array function for that:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

```
if (in_array($value, $array))
{
echo $value . ' is in the array!';
}
```

Comment: Uh, whoops? Must have read over this part:
`The code I've got work only works for an exact match (and is the wrong way) so output here would be false but I need a true...`
Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$array = Array( 
   0 => 'word1',
   1 => 'word2',
   2 => 'word3'
);

$string = "there a good word3 here";

function findInArray($string, $array) {
    for ($x=0; $x < count($array); $x++) {
        if (preg_match('/\b' . $array[$x] . '\b/', $string)) { // The \b in the pattern indicates a word boundary, so only the distinct 
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

if (findInArray($string, $array)) {
   // do stuff
}
```